# Горизонтальное масштабирование средствами ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Как реализуется горизонтальное масштабирование средствами этого фреймворка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак. Для этого используется Bootstrap, Jquery, HTML5 и т.д., если речь о рендере.